# no type named 'u16string' in namespace 'std' on macOS Sierra

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator

Pretty much all the solutions to this question boil down to

Use `CONFIG += c++11` in the `.pro` file or use `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`. Unfortunately none of those solutions worked for me. I'm still getting the error. I have to add that I had to move this project from a `Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` machine to a `Mac macOS Sierra 10.12` machine. The error started happening after the move. As you will see from the output, I'm running `Qt 5.6.2`

Here is contents of my `.pro` file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-10-05T10:30:33
#
#-------------------------------------------------
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = gui
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

CONFIG += c++11

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -ferror-limit=1
```

and here is the actual command that runs and fails:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -pipe -ferror-limit=1 -g -std=gnu++0x -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../gui -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/mkspecs/macx-g++ -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib -o main.o ../gui/main.cpp
In file included from ../gui/main.cpp:1:
In file included from ../gui/mainwindow.h:4:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/QMainWindow:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qmainwindow.h:37:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers/qwidget.h:38:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qobject.h:41:
/usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.6.2/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qstring.h:756:55: error: no type named 'u16string' in namespace 'std'
    static inline QString fromStdU16String(const std::u16string &s);
                                                 ~~~~~^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

And here is the output of 
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/g++ --version`

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: Looking at the `g++` configuration...`--with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`. Does that mean it is using the standard library from GCC 4.2? That is close to a decade old now (and wouldn't have `std::u16string`).

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. But your assumption is very reasonable. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32443773/1636521) seem to provide partial answer. Which is what I did initially, i.e. `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++`. But then I got a following warning `clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9`. Don't know where it came from, since I wasn't using `clang` for compilation. This gave me an idea to switch my project to `clang` which made it compile with no issues.

Comment: @flashburn: No experience with OSX, but it looks like your `g++ --version` output is telling you `g++` is really `clang`, right?

Comment: I would stick to Clang on OSX, since it is considered the native compiler these days. I suspect your issue was the old-as-dirt standard library implementation.